# VBA Code For copying and Pasting with If statement

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, copy-paste

I need to copy range **A1:G200** from one workbook to current workbook (both workbooks active) but I need the code to only copy the rows that meet a certain criteria in column G. Column G only has values ranging from .000 to .999. I need the macro to copy range **A1:G200** but only if they are between range **.250** and **.500** in column G.

I have already created the macro for copying and pasting, which works great but the problem is that I am not too familiar with If statements. Can anyone help me out? Here is what I have so far:

```
Sub test()

    Dim masterWb As Workbook
    Dim mySht As Worksheet
    Set mySht = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Set masterWb = Workbooks("JME") 
    With masterWb.Worksheets.Add
        .Range("A1:G200").Value = mySht.Range("A1:G200").Value
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: research the `if ... then ... else` statement. you cannot proceed without the knowledge

Answer (score 0):

One way which you could do this is by pasting the values row by row. Simply check column G for your criteria, and if the row meets the criteria, paste the values

```
Dim ColG As Range
Set ColG = mySht.Range("G1:G200")

Dim CopyCount As Integer
CopyCount = 0

With masterWb.Worksheets.Add
    For Each Cell In ColG
        ThisRow = Cell.Row
        If Cell.Value >= 0.25 And Cell.Value <= 0.5 Then
            CopyCount = CopyCount + 1
            .Range("A" & CopyCount & ":G" & CopyCount).Value = _
                mySht.Range("A" & ThisRow & ":G" & ThisRow).Value
        Else
            'Do Nothing
        End If
    Next Cell
End With
```

Let me know if this works for you. Enjoy!